# Move a div as a child tag to be same as parent using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="firstchild">Item 1</div>
    <div class="secondchild">Item 2</div>
    <div class="tirthchild">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to move one of the div child to be the same as the parent? So the result will look like this:

```
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="firstchild">Item 1</div>
    <div class="secondchild">Item 2</div>
</div>

<div class="tirthchild">Item 3</div>
```

Thank you very much for any answer

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to move an element with css. Try to think for change of your layout, probably It may be done by CSS only.

Answer (score -2):

Sure, use `parent1.parentNode.appendChild(child)`

```js
const parent1 = document.querySelector(".parent1");
      
document.body.addEventListener("click", e =>
{
  const child = e.target; //clicked div
  parent1.parentNode.appendChild(child); //move item as last element inside parent
});
```

```css
body > div
{
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.parent1 > div
{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

div:before
{
  content: "click me ";
}
body > div:after
{
  content: " next to parent";
}

.parent1 > div:after
{
  content: " inside parent";
}

.parent1:after
{
  content: " parent";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="firstchild">Item 1</div>
    <div class="secondchild">Item 2</div>
    <div class="tirthchild">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time to answer my question. But, I need to move the tag just using CSS, without JS.